# How to properly perform code coverage of every python file in a repo?

Tags: python

I'm using this library https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/v4.5.x/cmd.html

There are bunch of files and directories in a repo

I'm running bash script to interate through every python file and perform `coverage run a.py`

Is there any way to run a summarized result? Maybe create a big XML file as a summary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [combine python coverage files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26214055/combine-python-coverage-files)

Answer (score 0):

You can run coverage with a '-a' option to add the results for successive executables.

```
coverage run A.py
coverage run -a B.py
coverage run -a C.py
...
coverage html -d coverage-report
```